# How to make `margin: top;` based on browser height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The title pretty much says it all. I want the CSS `margin: top;` on my HTML `main_content` element to be relative to (a percentage of) the browser window (so that the `main_content` always stays on the bottom of the browser window. How can I accomplish this?

---

I've tried this and it doesn't work. (the `body {height:100vh}` doesn't seem to make `body` any height as the `main_content` doesn't stick to the bottom as it should.

```css
body {height:100vh}
#main_content {position:absolute; width:100%; display:block; left:0; bottom:0; text-align:center; padding:20px;}
```

```html
<div>Extra Infomation </div>
<div id="main_content">
<p>here you can learn about me and my adventures</p>
</div>
```

(Don't try this right now) If you go to my [website](http://www.jeffarries.com), you will see the "learn about me and my adventures" heading, that, along with the "recent activity", and other stuff below that, that is the section I want at the bottom of the browser window, preferably with the "learn about me and my adventures" part just sticking out from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Give `margin-top` value in `%`

Comment: Yes, but that's the percentage of the width of the browser window, not the percentage of the height of the browser window.

Comment: whats the point of that -- you could use position:fixed; with bottom:10%; -- https://jsfiddle.net/5xs1hct0/ -- unlses you mean something else -- do a demo

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Updated post, please take a look at that.

Comment: @Tasos `fixed` doesn't work because I need to have elements below it and it needs to be in normal flow (be scrollable).

Comment: you have #main_content  and you are using class  --  stick a dot instead of the hash

Comment: The best solution is using Javascript to find the window size and then set the height.

Comment: @Tasos Thanks! I see that, however that was a writing mistake. It's not that issue.

Comment: @goncalopinto What code do I use to do that?  I don't know JavaScript well, Thanks!

Comment: I need to have elements below it  -- do a full demo so we can get the idea

Comment: Running your code above it sticks to the bottom of the window for me.

Comment: @kojow7 Yes it does for me too, but it doesn't work on my website (link in post).

Comment: @Tasos Made update, please take a look at that!

Comment: You have a CSS solution by symlink.

Comment: On your page, it's not set to absolute.

Comment: @kojow7 Yes, I'm updating and trying other people's answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give .main_content a margin-top of 100vh (just beneath the viewport), and then use transformY to pull it back up:

```css
.main_content {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 100vh;
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 20px));
 background:lightblue;
}
.below_content{
 margin-top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Extra Infomation </div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <p>here you can learn about me and my adventures</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="below_content">
    This is content below the main content
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! How is cross-browser compatibility for `transform: translateY(-100%);`??

Comment: Also, if the screen get's smaller i.e. a iPhone 4, then if is further down than when it is on my computer, why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform 2D transformations are supported by all the major browsers.

Comment: I updated the code to use calc to accommodate the padding, and pull the `below_content` up so it's flush with the bottom of `main_content`. Not sure about the iPhone, I'll check it out.

Comment: Looks good to me on an iPhone 4 emulator. Maybe the update fixed the problem. Are you still seeing the problem?

Comment: The problem is still there, but it's minor and it's not a big issue. Thank you a lot for fixing this problem! It was troubling me greatly.

Comment: Happy to help, it's an interesting question.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank your!

Answer (score 0):

so put a `.` before main_content if it is a class and put  `#` if it is an id.

below css code for main_content id should work.

```
#main_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can try is here https://jsfiddle.net/xsdr00dn/